# How to reset onyx.Picker to pre selected state

Tags: javascript, enyo

I have an onyx.Picker which before selection displays a "Click to Select" button prompting the user for action.  As is the expected behavior, once the user picks an option, they can not revert back to the "Click to Select" display.  However, I need to be able to programmatically reset the form, in which case, the picker should once again revert to it's original state.

I have figured out that I can remove the picked option by calling `this.$.PickerName.setSelected(null)` However, the UI does not revert back to the "Click to Select" display as would be expected.  How can I reset the picker completely?

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/trex005/2amLu1r4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i am aware, `setSelected()` on the picker expects you to pass it a reference to the control (picker's clientControls) which you want to set dynamically ,so passing `null` will do nothing. Once an item is selected, the list of items closes, but the item stays selected and the `pickerButton` displays the choice that was made. So, all you have to do is this. `this.$.pickerButton.setContent('Click to Select');` which will reset the pickerButton content.

http://jsfiddle.net/scrs3Le5/1/

```
enyo.create({
components: [{
    kind: "onyx.PickerDecorator",
    name: "DecoratorName",
    components: [{
        name:'pickerButton',
        style: 'min-height:2.5rem;min-width:330px;',
        content: "Click to Select"
    }, {
        kind: 'onyx.Picker',
        name: 'PickerName',
        components: [
            {content: "Is broken"},
            {content: "Is not cool"},
            {content: "Is very very very very very very very cool!"}
        ]
    }]
}, {
    kind: 'Button',
    ontap: 'ResetPicker',
    content: 'ResetPicker'
}],
ResetPicker: function () {
    //this.$.PickerName.setSelected(null);
    this.$.pickerButton.setContent('Click to Select');
},
rendered: function () {
    this.inherited(arguments);
}
}).renderInto(document.body);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, it helps VERY much.  However, the picker, although displaying "Click to Select" actually has still has the previously picked control selected.  So you still need the line you commented out to fix that part.

Comment: I was going to suggest a pull request to add a reset method but the picker doesn't preserve the default content for the PickerButton.  Perhaps a reorg of the pickers is needed.